# The Instantiate() function is instantiating the clone

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, invoke

[image]I am trying to instantiate one instance of the prefab "Cube" whenever I click the right mouse button. But the problem is my code instantiates the clone of the prefab, which creates the clone of the clone and so on. I wanted the instance of prefab only and one at a click. Please help me through this. Thank You!

ps : Please tell me if i'm not clear.

Comment: Please post your code, not screenshots of your code.

Comment: My browser doesn't show images, cant read your code

Comment: It's gotta be more difficult to insert an image than to copy/paste text. I don't understand why anyone does this. Paste your code, not pictures of it.

Comment: You don't ever set the stop spawning flag to true. You also should move the check to the top of the function for the stop spawning

Comment: Why would you include *two, separate, identical* images of your code in your post?

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate a prefab it puts "(Clone)" in the object's name. If you want to remove "(Clone)" you can modify the name of the object after instantiation.

```
GameObject newSpawner = (GameObject)Instantiate(spawner, position, rotation);     
newSpawner.name = "Spawner";
```